# How to have different attributes for different nodes with the same recipe?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I'm using Chef Zero (or Chef Local mode), can't use a server. I have a cookbook with a default recipe I want to run. In my scenario, I want to run that recipe more than once for each search/node except with different attributes.

**important part of recipe:**

```
keepalived_vrrp_instance 'inside_network' do
  state node['cookbookname']['state']
  interface node['network']['default_interface']
  virtual_router_id node['cookbookname']['router_id']
  priority node['cookbookname']['priority']
  virtual_ipaddress node['cookbookname']['virtual_ips']
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define hash of attributes for each node name ([attributes](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html) can be defined in attribute file or [environement](https://docs.chef.io/environments.html)):

```
node.default["cookbookname"] = {
  "node1" => {
    "state" => "desired_state"
    ...
  }
  "node2" => { ... }
  ...
}
```

Then you can use it in recipe:

```
keepalived_vrrp_instance 'inside_network' do
  state node["cookbookname"][node["name"]]["state"]
  ...
end
```